# Should the underlying container of a priority_queue be considered a complete binary tree?

Tags: c++, priority-queue, heap

Say I'm using a `std::vector` as the underlying container of a `std::priority_queue`.

Should I consider this vector as a representation of a binary heap (Becz., a priority_queue is similar to a heap (Am I right in this assumption? An awful lot of sources on the web use these 2 terms interchangeably)? or is it just a normal vector?

By "representation of a binary heap" I mean -> 0th element of the vector is the root of the bin. heap, 1st element is the left child of the root, 2nd element is the right child & so on.

Comment: *"Should I consider this vector as a representation of a binary heap"* -- why not consider the vector as a representation of a `std::priority_queue` and not worry about deeper details?

Comment: C++ standard does not guarantee that. In a specific implementation of C++ standard library this may hold but fail once you use another implementation. If you need the elements of the vector, you can just use `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap`, `std::pop_heap` from the beginning

Comment: Are you just curious, or planning to access the underlying data directly (which would be very fragile).

Comment: @PepijnKramer I want to calculate the median of a group of numbers. I thought I can push all those numbers into a priority_queue & access the element at middle (if the underlying vector is interpreted as just a vector & not complete binary tree).

Comment: @erzya I can't use the method you suggested for my case, can I?

Comment: it is probably easier just putting everything in a vector and using std::sort then pick the middle. Both should be around N log(N) complexity

Comment: @PhiloRobotist Since your goal is a heap rather than a priority queue, why don't you use a heap? Going after your goal indirectly tends to result in confusing code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the standard mandates that the member functions of `priority_queue` have the same effect as applying the relevant heap operation to the underlying container:

> `void push(const value_type& x);`
>
> Effects: As if by:
>
> ```
> c.push_back(x); 
> push_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
> ```
>
> `void push(value_type&& x);`
>
> Effects: As if by:
>
> ```
> c.push_back(std::move(x)); 
> push_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
> ```
>
> `template<container-compatible-range<T> R> void push_range(R&& rg);`
>
> Effects: Insert all elements of rg in c.
>
> Postconditions: `is_­heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp)` is true.
>
> `template<class... Args> void emplace(Args&&... args);`
>
> Effects: As if by:
>
> ```
> c.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
> push_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
> ```
>
> `void pop();`
>
> Effects: As if by:
>
> ```
> pop_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp); 
> c.pop_back();
> ```

[priqueue.members](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/priqueue.members)

Because the underlying container is a protected member, and access controls apply to naming the member, you can get at any `priority_queue`s data, even if it isn't a base-subobject of a class you've defined.

```
template <typename T, typename Container, typename Comp>
const Container & get_container(const std::priority_queue<T, Container, Comp> & queue) {
    struct access_t : std::priority_queue<T, Container, Comp> {
        auto member_ptr() { return &access_t::c; }
    } access;
    auto ptr = access.member_ptr();
    return queue.*ptr;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers my question.

Comment: @PhiloRobotist the member functions of `std::priority_queue` are defined in terms of `std::push_heap`, `std::pop_heap`, and the constructors in terms of `std::make_heap`. I've edited to show one way you can observe the data in the queue.